# Is there a way to detect changes in a div tag whose data is injected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vue.js, javascript-injection

Everything else listed online either doesn't seem to work or is now deprecated. Ive heard of mutation observers but can't find sufficient documentation online anywhere.

It's a normal  tag whose contents are updated by a js file. I need to be able to detect every change on this div that is injected and apply a css property to the div when the text changes. (It does this often, approx once every 2 seconds).

Anyone here know how to approach this?

Comment: If it is updated with a database values then you might look into websockets.

Comment: Assuming there are no events raised by the logic which updates the HTML, then you could certainly use a MutationObserver. There's lots of documentation at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver, although as @Jai recommends, if you need to keep the client UI in sync with server data with a latency of ~2 seconds, WebSockets or Server Sent Events would be a much better idea.

Comment: @Jai that has absolutely nothing to do with what I asked. I need to be able to detect changes made in the DOM of a divider using javascript and then apply a css property to said div.

Comment: It does. Assuming you can change how the data is provided to the page, a socket connection would be a much better than polling every 2 seconds.

Comment: Typically looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), hence why you get comments that you may not understand how they can be related to your issue description. You have a script (maybe Vue since you tagged it) that modifies DOM, and you want to apply further modifications (CSS) when that happens. So you try to detect DOM modification (=> MutationObserver) and ask for help on that. But in fact you need to modify your script so that it does your extra modification at the same time it changes the DOM.

Comment: Related - [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570614/104380)